# Creating a NetSuite Restlet to pull files from Communications tab of a Vendor Bill

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, restlet, suitescript2.0

I am currently trying to create a NetSuite restlet that searches through all my vendor bills for bills that have a file in the Communications tab and then downloads the file.

My issue is that I can't seem to access the Files Sublist within the Communications tab. It looks likes the Files Sublist is a STATICLIST type (which isn't available for scripting according to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4332704307.html)), so I need a workaround.

Has anyone dealt with this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a customization similar with this problem before. You should be using a Saved Search and add your Vendor Bill ID as filter. There is a field called `File (Line) Fields...` and `File Fields...`. You can make use of their internal IDs.